# Volley android diplays not data from json without showing any Errors

Tags: android-volley

I am building an android application. My code shows no errors neither the LogCat but when i run my app i get only the dialog "Loading...." and nothing more. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

AppController

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static AppController mInstance;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance=this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getmInstance(){
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getmRequestQueue(){
    if(mRequestQueue == null){
        mRequestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getmImageLoader(){
    getmRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader==null){
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new BitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue (Request<T> request, String tag){
    request.setTag((TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag));
    getmRequestQueue().add(request);
}


private <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
    request.setTag(TAG);
    getmRequestQueue().add(request);
}


public void cancelPendingRequest (Object tag){
    if (mRequestQueue!=null){
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

this is my ItemAdapter (my customized Adapter)

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Item> items;
private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
public ItemAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items){
    this .activity = activity;
    this.items=items;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
    }
    if (imageLoader==null){
        imageLoader=AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titile);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        Item.ResultsEntity item = (Item.ResultsEntity) getItem(position);
        imageView.setImageUrl(item.getPoster_120x171(),imageLoader);
        title.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTitle()));
        rating.setText(String.valueOf(item.getRating()));

    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

this is my mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String url = "http://api-public.guidebox.com/v1.43/Tunisia/rKgEWJbFg0kgEHrcGXPKhPDo0XtTafyC/movies/all/250/250";
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private List<Item> array=new ArrayList<Item>();
private ListView listView;
private ItemAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, array);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading.... ");
    dialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            hideDialog();
            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item.ResultsEntity item = new Item.ResultsEntity();
                    item.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    item.setPoster_120x171(obj.getString("poster_120x171"));
                    item.setRating(obj.getString("rating"));

                }catch (JSONException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });

    AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest,url);
}

public void hideDialog(){
    if (dialog!=null){
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog=null;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Finally this is the LogCat

```
05-12 03:22:28.582      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
05-12 03:22:28.622      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G3815_4.4.2_0046
05-12 03:22:28.622      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
05-12 03:22:28.622      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson [ userId:0 | appId:10201 ]
05-12 03:22:28.622      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14536: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14540: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
05-12 03:22:28.862      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
05-12 03:22:28.893      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-12 03:22:28.893      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 420: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-12 03:22:28.893      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-12 03:22:28.893      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-12 03:22:28.893      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 442: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-12 03:22:28.893      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-12 03:22:28.963      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-12 03:22:29.113      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1__release_AU ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
Build Date: 03/25/14 Tue
Local Branch:
Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.32
Local Patches: NONE
Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
05-12 03:22:29.143      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-12 03:22:29.153      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-12 03:22:29.153      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-12 03:22:29.153      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 72
05-12 03:22:29.153      813-813/movies.esprit.tn.edu.moviesparsingjson D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 72
```

Comment: Run your app in *Debug Mode* you may get some idea where it is not working

Comment: I guess that i have a threading problem since it tells me that there is "too much work" statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i got no answer for this issue, i worked with Retrofit and it worked like a charm. In case anyone got the same issue